# Why does the std::find for vector return a iterator instead of the integer position

Tags: c++, std

Why does the vector find return the iterator instead of the integer value?

```
vector<string>::iterator itr1 = std::find(words.begin(), words.end(), word);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) works for all sorts of containers, not just `std::vector`. For example, it works with `std::list` but that container does not allow accessing elements by index (at least not easily). For it to work with all kinds of containers it needs to return something all containers understand, an iterator.

Edit : If you want to find the index position equivalent to a given iterator, you can use [`std::distance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance). For example :

`std::distance(std::begin(words), itr1);`

This will work for standard containers but it may be slower for some. It returns the size of the container if the element is not found, since `find` returns `end` if it fails to find the element and the distance between `begin` and `end` is the size of the container.

Comment: Is it possible to find all the indexes of occurrences of the word in the vector?

Comment: @Gani Yes, perform the search in a loop. Instead of searching from `begin` to `end`, replace `begin` by the iterator following the last one you found. I don't think the standard library has a function for that.

Comment: @Gani: Why do you want indices so badly? What's wrong with using iterators?

Comment: Iterators are the glue that holds containers and algorithms together.  I've seen several 3rd party collection libraries, and none of them had iterators.  They also didn't have algorithms because they (we) couldn't get them to work with enough containers without 'em.

Comment: @NicolBolas I am working on some algorithm which needs all the indexes to be stored in the vector. Its easy to code for it but I was just curious if the STL library has something for me.

Comment: @Gani It's the standard library, or std library. STL is something else and essentially unused anymore. [What's the difference between “STL” and “C++ Standard Library”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205491/whats-the-difference-between-stl-and-c-standard-library) Someone else already edited your question to reflect this.